# Sort a List by a date present in another list

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have such a situation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ObjectA {
      private Integer id;
      private String code;
      private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class ObjectB {
      private Integer id;
      private Timestamp createdOn;
}
```

I have to sort a `List<ObjectA>` which also contains the ids of the `List<ObjectB>` and the sorting must be:

- by descending date of the "createdOn" attribute of the `List<ObjectB>` included in the `List<ObjectA>` and distinguishable from the ids
- by descending name
- by descending code

With this i sort by name and code with .sort() and comparators:

```
 listA.sort(o -> o.getName())
                .thenComparing(o -> o.getCode()).reversed();
```

The part that I cannot produce is the sorting of the list based on an attribute that is not present in the list that is being sorted but in another distinguishable by ids.

Thank u all for the help.

Comment: You'd neet to map A elements to their B counterparts via their id. For performance reasons I'd suggest to build a map for B and then map in the comparator, e.g. `Comparator.comparing(a -> mapOfB.get(a.getId()).getCreatedOn())`. Of course you'd have to handle non-existant mappings (i.e. `get()` returning null) etc.

Comment: not all the contents of the List<ObjectA> are present in the List<ObjectB> - it would go to NullPointer

Comment: Exactly, that's what I was refering to in my last sentence. Don't expect production-ready solutions on SO. You'll often get outlines or simplified code to get you started but there's still some effort you need to put into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you convert list of ObjectB into a `Map<id, createdOn>` as retrieving elements by key is O(1) in Map but O(n) in List.

```
Map<Integer, Timestamp> createdOnMap =
    bList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectB::getId, ObjectB::getCreatedOn));
```

Then compare by getting the value of this map, and if it's not present decide whether to place it as first or last in the list by comparing the value against a maximum/minimum value. An example with LocalDateTime:

```
aList.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(objectA -> createdOnMap.getOrDefault(objectA.getId(), LocalDateTime.MAX)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

In the scenario that createdOnMap doesn't have a value for this id, it compares against `LocalDateTime.MAX/MIN`.

If you also want to have in the final list elements that are not present in List but are in List, then you'll need to add those elements by yourself before sorting by converting ObjectB to ObjectA.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Timestamp> mapOfB = listB.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectB::getId,
                                                                ObjectB::getCreatedOn));

listA.sort(Comparator.comparing(o-> mapOfB.get(((ObjectA)o).getId()),
                                Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                     .thenComparing(o->((ObjectA)o).getName())
                     .thenComparing(o->((ObjectA)o).getCode(), Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Comment: @Thomas thank you, I'm agree with you, solution is too expemsive. Yayotrón's solution really nice.

Comment: @Thomas I've changed my answer